# なぜbs4で要素を取得することができないのでしょうか？

Tags: python

このコードはグーグル翻訳に英文を飛ばして、翻訳されたものを取得しようとしたプログラムです。PhantomJSを用いた類似プログラムではうまくspan要素を取得できたのですが、bs4を用いた、コードではこれがうまく取得できません。

この違いはなんなのか、誰か分かる方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

```
import pyperclip, requests, bs4, pprint

res = requests.get('https://translate.google.co.jp/?hl=ja#en/ja/' + pyperclip.paste())
res.raise_for_status() 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
elems = soup.select('span')
for i in range(len(elems)):
 print(elems[i].getText())
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/102240

Comment: マルチポスト関連の記事は一読させていただきました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- グーグル翻訳は**javascriptが動作する環境**でしか「**翻訳できません**」。
- Python の `requests` では **javascript動かして**ページを取得することはできません。
- javascriptが必要になるページを**動的なページ** と呼び、HTML/CSSだけのようなページをを**静的なページ**と呼んだりします。
- PhantomJS は **ヘッドレスブラウザ** と呼ばれるライブラリの一つで、ブラウザと同様に**javascript**を実行して **動的なページ** を取得できます。

Python で **動的なページ** をスクレイピングしたい時も、結局 PhantomJSなりを用意して、それをSeleniumなどのライブラリを通して使ったりします。

Python, Selenium, WebDriver, PhantomJS あたりのキーワードでやり方はいっぱい出てくると思うのでググってみてください。

Comment: 分かりやすい説明本当にありがとうございます。最後のsele+pjsでやるやり方は取得できました。一方でrequests.get()したもを確認しましたが、翻訳結果ははいっていませんでした。理由は「動的」ということだったんですね。本当に助かりました。ありがとうございます。